# Connection Mysql fails

Tags: command-line, java, mysql

I need a little help installing/connecting an application to a mysql database.
First time I faced many problems/errors, the most of them are gone and this is the result stull nothing haha...
Does somebody know the right way?
Below you can find the log.

```
ws02@ws02:/usr/bin/wso2/wso2emm-2.0.1/bin$ sudo -E  ./wso2server.sh -Dsetup
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /usr/bin/wso2/wso2emm-2.0.1
Using Java memory options: -Xms256m -Xmx1024m
[2016-05-08 03:18:17,379]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.appmgt.impl.internal.AppDiscoveryComponent} -  WebApp Discovery component activated
[2016-05-08 03:18:17,424]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.appmgt.mobile.internal.AppManagerMobileComponent} -  WSO2MDM_INTERNAL MDM is bound to App Manager
[2016-05-08 03:18:17,424]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.appmgt.mobile.internal.AppManagerMobileComponent} -  App Manger Mobile Component activated
[2016-05-08 03:18:18,083]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Starting WSO2 Carbon...
[2016-05-08 03:18:18,084]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Operating System : Linux 4.4.0-21-generic, amd64
[2016-05-08 03:18:18,084]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Home        : /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/jre
[2016-05-08 03:18:18,085]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Version     : 1.8.0_91
[2016-05-08 03:18:18,085]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.91-b14,Oracle Corporation
[2016-05-08 03:18:18,085]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Carbon Home      : /usr/bin/wso2/wso2emm-2.0.1
[2016-05-08 03:18:18,085]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Temp Dir    : /usr/bin/wso2/wso2emm-2.0.1/tmp
[2016-05-08 03:18:18,086]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  User             : root, nl-NL, Europe/Amsterdam
[2016-05-08 03:18:18,494]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.util.ValidationResultPrinter} -  Maximum PermGen space (MB) :0 of the running JVM is set below the recommended minimum size :256
[2016-05-08 03:18:18,495]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.util.ValidationResultPrinter} -  Carbon is configured to use the default keystore (wso2carbon.jks). To maximize security when deploying to a production environment, configure a new keystore with a unique password in the production server profile.
Activating org.wso2.jaggery.scxml with RealmService enabled
[2016-05-08 03:18:24,330] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator} -  Cannot start User Manager Core bundle
java.lang.Exception: Error in creating the database
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeDatabase(DefaultRealmService.java:338)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:88)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:112)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:68)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Error occurred while executing :   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS REG_RESOURCE ( REG_PATH_ID         INTEGER NOT NULL, REG_NAME            VARCHAR(256), REG_VERSION         INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, REG_MEDIA_TYPE      VARCHAR(500), REG_CREATOR         VARCHAR(31) NOT NULL, REG_CREATED_TIME    TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, REG_LAST_UPDATOR    VARCHAR(31), REG_LAST_UPDATED_TIME    TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, REG_DESCRIPTION     VARCHAR(1000), REG_CONTENT_ID      INTEGER, REG_TENANT_ID INTEGER DEFAULT 0, REG_UUID VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_REG_RESOURCE PRIMARY KEY(REG_VERSION, REG_TENANT_ID) )ENGINE INNODB
    at org.wso2.carbon.utils.dbcreator.DatabaseCreator.executeSQL(DatabaseCreator.java:169)
    at org.wso2.carbon.utils.dbcreator.DatabaseCreator.executeSQLScript(DatabaseCreator.java:325)
    at org.wso2.carbon.utils.dbcreator.DatabaseCreator.createRegistryDatabase(DatabaseCreator.java:61)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeDatabase(DefaultRealmService.java:328)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Invalid default value for 'REG_CREATED_TIME'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:939)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2547)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2505)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:840)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:740)
    at org.wso2.carbon.utils.dbcreator.DatabaseCreator.executeSQL(DatabaseCreator.java:139)
    ... 22 more
[2016-05-08 03:21:29,785]  INFO {org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule} -  TLD skipped. URI: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles is already defined
```

Hope somebody can help me with it im not the linux professional.

Comment: Have you tried the typical steps to check that mysql is working properly? i.e.: is the service up, the port listening, can you log in from terminal as root/user?

Comment: Hey Julen,

Mysql is running I also can manually add and drop databases without a problem, I just dont know where this error is from.

The first error starts here :

[2016-05-08 03:18:24,330] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator} -  Cannot start User Manager Core bundle
java.lang.Exception: Error in creating the database

Comment: I think this question should go to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

As you enclosed, it is from the log:

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   Invalid default value for 'REG_CREATED_TIME'

According to this there is no problem with Ubuntu or linux. It's a Java problem and the log is a Java stacktrace.

### Update:

OK, I did some investigation and I tried out you want to install an Enterprise Service Bus ESB server, which is written in Java. When you run the script, it try to initialize the DB with some default value. But It can't be finished, because this error (see above).

I think the different version of MySQL cause this error or JDBC connector version difference.

You should follow this [Doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB460/Installing+on+Linux) or get in touch with the developers.

Comment: Hey Ampika, Mysql is running I also can manually add and drop databases without a problem, I just dont know where this error is from. The first error starts here : [2016-05-08 03:18:24,330] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator} - Cannot start User Manager Core bundle java.lang.Exception: Error in creating the database

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with MySql 5.7. A workaround is mentioned here[1]

Workaound:

> set GLOBAL
>   sql_mode="ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION";

​

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-4645